# The columns highlighting for copypaste

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I would like to create a webage with a bilingual text side by side. And i think it needs to be DIV, not TABLE layouting. The first column will be the original text, and the second will be the translation. 
What i need is to be able to inline ajax edit the text of the tranlation column per div.
But the main problem for me is to be able to highlight with the mouse for copy/pasting purposes just the given column.
Any ideas how do i do that?

here's a simple prototype of what i need

[image]

Comment: That's a screenshot of a JSFiddle project, why not post a link to the fiddle so we can experience what you mean?

Comment: its a table. i dont need a table, it was just for the mockup purpose

Comment: Then you have multiple questions .... limit at one per question on SO

Comment: well, have no idea how it will help you, but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/wfEr9/

Comment: @Danko, no, its not. It is only about the highlighting. But i had to mension about the height of the paragraphs and that i will make them editable, because it needs to be considered before the answer is given.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the code below and in case you need to make them server tag, that also easy, give each tag an id and add runat='server'

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left;"> left pane </div>
  <div style="float:right;">right pane </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add width:50% to the style otherwise you wont get two columns. But this will work (supposing we understand his question)

Comment: @Gautam Beri, did you try to HIGHLIGHT the column, created with the given code with the mouse, to copy lets say only the right column content? any luck? mate, try to read the question title, plz.

Comment: are you trying to perform click copy on the div tag ? you may want to either add a button or place an on click on the div tag. See this link they have a similar example. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3458851 hope this helps